# Remove single To-do list and prevent empty list

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner learning JavaScript at present and I want to make a to-do app as my first project in javascript but there seems to be some complications.
Firstly, i can create an empty list which suppose not to occur secondly, I can't delete a single To-do list.
I know my code is not okay but I will be happy if someone can solve it this way.
Thanks in advance source code below

```
HTML CODE
<div><input type ="text"id="input-el" placeholder="Enter your list of to do here...">
<button id="save-el">createlist</button>
<button id="delete-el">Delete list </button>
<div>
<ul id="ul-el"></ul>

  //Javascript CODE
 let todo = [];
   let inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el");
 const saveEl = document.getElementById("save-el");
 const deleteEl = document.getElementById("delete-el");
 const xEl = document.getElementById("x-el");
 let items= document.getElementById("items");
 let ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el");
 let listItems = ""

   //FUNCTION USE TO ADD NEW TO-DO LIST
   function myfunc(){
  let listItems = ""
for(let i=0;i<todo.length;i++) {
    listItems += `
    <li id='${items}'><span>
     <input class='check' type ='checkbox'></span>${todo[i]} <button id='x-el'>x</button></li>
`   
}
 ulEl.innerHTML = listItems;}

  //SAVE TO-DO LIST
    if(inputEl !== ""){    saveEl.addEventListener("click",function(){
   todo.push(inputEl.value);
   inputEl.value = "";
   myfunc()
  })
}
   else {
      alert("can't create an empty list")
 }

 //TO DELETE ALL TO-DO LIST    
 deleteEl.addEventListener("dblclick",function(){
  todo = [];
  saveEl.value = "";
  inputEl.value = "";
  myfunc()
})

 //TO REMOVE A SINGLE TO-DO LIST FROM ALL LIST
 /*items.addEventListener('click', 
 function(e) {
 this.removeChild(e.target);
 })*/
```

I comments some codes out when it doesn't work, I will be happy if you can solve this issue using my approach

Comment: `let input-el` this is no good, dashes are not legal in javascript variable names

Comment: also, your elements have id `save-El` and `delete-El` which are case-sensitive, `document.getElementById("save-el");` and `document.getElementById("delete-el");` don't match the selector.

Comment: here's an edited working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/so2dau6q/1/

Comment: It was a mistake on editing thanks for checking it out

Answer (score 1):

This project can be done without using an array to store tasks. I hope this will solve your problem.

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="inputEl" placeholder="Enter your list of to do here...">
    <button id="saveEl">createlist</button>
    <button id="deleteEl">Delete list</button>
    <ul id="ulEl"></ul>


    <script>

        let inputEl = document.getElementById("inputEl")
        let saveEl = document.getElementById("saveEl")
        let ulEl = document.getElementById("ulEl")
        let deleteEl = document.getElementById("deleteEl")


        //ADD NEW ELEMENT TO LIST
        saveEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
            var task = document.createElement("li")
            task.innerText = inputEl.value
            ulEl.appendChild(task)

            //REMOVE SINGLE TASK  
            task.addEventListener("click", function() {
                ulEl.removeChild(task)
            })
        })

        //DELETE ALL ELEMENTS
        deleteEl.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
            ulEl.innerText = ""
        })


    </script>
</body>
```